# Using SQL raw query in SQlite for joining tables

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have three tables(IncidentCategory, IncidentQuestion, IncidentOption) and  in which I need to fire one join query to arrange and select some data. For same, some SQL Server developers have written one query like below:

> SERVER QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM [IncidentQuestion] AS IQ WHERE IQ.[IncidentCategoryId]=27 AND  
IQ.[IsOption]=0 AND (SELECT COUNT(IO.[Id]) FROM [dbo]. [IncidentOption] AS 
IO WHERE IO.[IncidentQuestionId]=IQ.[Id])<>0 ORDER BY IQ.[OrderId] ASC;

DECLARE @False BIT; SET @False=0;SELECT IP.*,COALESCE(IV.[Id], 0) AS    
[IncidentValueId],COALESCE(IV.[IsChecked], @False) AS [IsChecked],IV.
[Value],IV.IncidentId FROM [IncidentOption] AS IP LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM 
[IncidentValue] WHERE [IncidentId]=0) AS IV ON IP.[Id]=IV.[IncidentOptionId] 
WHERE IP.[IncidentQuestionId]=68 ORDER BY IP.[OrderId] ASC;
```

In my app, I have created the tables with same column names as in server.

IncidentQuestion DbHelper:

```
private static final String INCIDENT_QUESTION_TABLE = "IncidentQuestionTable";
private static final String ID = "_id";
private static final String SERVER_ID = "Id";
private static final String CONTRACT_TYPE_ID = "ContractTypeId";
private static final String INCIDENT_CATAGORY_ID = "IncidentCategoryId";
private static final String QTEXT = "QText";
private static final String TYPE = "Type";  
private static final String ORDER_ID = "OrderId";
private static final String IS_MANDATORY = "IsMandatory";
private static final String IS_OPTION = "IsOption";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "IncidentQuestion";

private final Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
private DbHelper ourHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String locationQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + INCIDENT_QUESTION_TABLE + " ("
                + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + SERVER_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + CONTRACT_TYPE_ID
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + INCIDENT_CATAGORY_ID
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + QTEXT
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + TYPE
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ORDER_ID
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + IS_MANDATORY
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + IS_OPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

        db.execSQL(locationQuery);      

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + INCIDENT_QUESTION_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

IncidentOption DbHelper:

```
private static final String INCIDENT_OPTION_TABLE = "IncidentOptionTable";
private static final String ID = "_id";
private static final String SERVER_ID = "Id";
private static final String INCIDENT_QUESTION_ID = "IncidentQuestionId";
private static final String OPTION_TEXT = "OptionText";
private static final String ORDER_ID = "OrderId";
private static final String PARENT_ID = "ParentId";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "IncidentOption";

private final Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
private DbHelper ourHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String locationQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + INCIDENT_OPTION_TABLE + " ("
                + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + SERVER_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + INCIDENT_QUESTION_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + OPTION_TEXT
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ORDER_ID
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + PARENT_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

        db.execSQL(locationQuery);      

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + INCIDENT_OPTION_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}
```

All Select, Insert, Create, Delete query are working perfectly, I am unable to convert and fore the server query in my local db. Can please any one help me to find out the way that how I will write the server query in my local db OR how I will write some query which will work like the server query. Suggestions are mostly appreciable.

Comment: Remove the brackets.  I'm not sure what db you're using server side, but I've worked with postgres, mysql, and oracle and none of them used [] like that.

Comment: @GabeSechan - SQL Server uses `[]` brackets.

Comment: have you tried the same query by removing the [ ] brackets?

Comment: @Priya Unfortunately I have different databases.. I have to attach all databases before firing queries. But I don't  know where(in which class/db handler) to right the DB `attach` query and `join`query.

Comment: Even i thought why you are using two different db handlers. I've never tried attach database before. You can try that in any one of the db handlers. I'll also try this.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite supports [brackets] for compatibility with SQL Server; you don't need to remove them.

SQLite has no DECLARE.
In the query shown, `False` is the constant zero (which is also how SQLite handles boolean values); just drop the DECLARE and SET, and replace `@False` with `0`.